# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1)

Tags: android

Any idea why I am getting this `sigsegv`

```
08-11 13:00:37.886: INFO/DEBUG(2188): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-11 13:00:37.886: INFO/DEBUG(2188): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/LT22i_1261-8592/LT22i:4.1.2/6.2.A.0.400/b_7_zg:user/release-keys'
08-11 13:00:37.886: INFO/DEBUG(2188): pid: 19011, tid: 19011, name: **  >>> com.** <<<
08-11 13:00:37.886: INFO/DEBUG(2188): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): r0 5c78ad00  r1 00000008  r2 00000018  r3 00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): r4 5b81a4bc  r5 5b870ec8  r6 00000010  r7 00000038
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): r8 00000000  r9 00000001  sl 5c78ad00  fp 00000001
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): ip 5c1fcda0  sp bec67988  lr 5c1e8cc8  pc 40042344  cpsr 20000010
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d0  0000000043bf8000  d1  3f8000003f000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d2  501502f9d01502f9  d3  0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d4  0000000000000000  d5  000000003f800000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d6  43bf800041a33b50  d7  bf80000043bf8000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d8  c0600000c0600000  d9  000001fe0000006e
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d10 403fda00000000b9  d11 403827485a00b037
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d12 438bbf244411d8e6  d13 403827485a00b037
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d14 431e290841c13a43  d15 4336507243365050
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d16 3007000010168b80  d17 0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d18 00000000017e8000  d19 0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d20 0000000000000000  d21 3ff0000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d22 4034676a00000000  d23 3ff0000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d26 4034676a00000000  d27 0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d28 bff0000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): scr 60000013
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): backtrace:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): #00  pc 0000e344  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+188)
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): #01  pc 00000030  <unknown>
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): stack:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67948  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6794c  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67950  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67954  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67958  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6795c  3ff00000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67960  5c9113a8
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67964  00000040
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67968  00000004
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6796c  5c794000  /dev/mali
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67970  10172000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67974  5c9113b0
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67978  00000038
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6797c  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67980  df0027ad
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67984  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): #00  bec67988  5c78ad00  /dev/mali
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6798c  5c1e8cc8  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so (_gles_gb_setup_input_streams+1808)
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67990  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67994  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67998  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec6799c  bec679b0  [stack]
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679a0  00000034
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): #01  bec679a4  5b81a488
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679a8  00008001
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679ac  00000001
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679b0  4002dbc8
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679b4  00000002
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679b8  00001406
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679bc  5c78ac00  /dev/mali
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679c0  00000008
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679c4  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679c8  00000262
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679cc  5b81a468
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679d0  00000000
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679d4  5c1f9ce4  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679d8  5c78e100  /dev/mali
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679dc  00000004
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679e0  10168d00
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near r0:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ace0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78acf0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near r4:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b81a49c 00000001 5c134c68 04040001 00008001  ....hL.\........
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b81a4ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  ...............?
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b81a4bc 00000002 00000010 00000010 00001406  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b81a4cc 00000008 00000000 00000000 04040001  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b81a4dc 00008001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near r5:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b870ea8 00000000 00000000 00000000 5ca24538  ............8E.\
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b870eb8 00000002 00000000 00000000 000000ab  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b870ec8 00000005 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b870ed8 bec67ec0 00000004 00000004 00000038  .~..........8...
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5b870ee8 00000001 00000000 00000037 00000000  ........7.......
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near sl:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ace0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78acf0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c78ad20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near ip:
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1fcd80 00000000 00000000 5d27b6d8 5d27b6e0  ..........']..']
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1fcd90 5d27ee00 5d283a84 5d283bb0 5d283a8c  ..'].:(].;(].:(]
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1fcda0 40042288 5d283648 5d292834 5d292848  .".@H6(]4()]H()]
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1fcdb0 5d27c9c0 5d2834d8 5d283960 5d2837a0  ..'].4(]`9(].7(]
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1fcdc0 5d2836bc 5d283718 5d283cd8 40042b54  .6(].7(].<(]T+.@
08-11 13:00:38.156: INFO/DEBUG(2188): memory near sp:
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67968 00000004 5c794000 10172000 5c9113b0  .....@y\. .....\
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67978 00000038 00000000 df0027ad 00000000  8........'......
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67988 5c78ad00 5c1e8cc8 00000000 00000000  ..x\...\........
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec67998 00000000 bec679b0 00000034 5b81a488  .....y..4......[
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): bec679a8 00008001 00000001 4002dbc8 00000002  ...........@....
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): code around pc:
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 40042324 f5d1f060 e2522040 f400020d f400420d  `...@ R......B..
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 40042334 2afffff7 e2822040 e2522020 3a000003  ...*@ ..  R....:
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 40042344 f421020d e2522020 f400020d 2afffffb  ..!.  R........*
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 40042354 e2822020 e3120010 0a000001 f4212a0d    ...........*!.
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 40042364 f4002a0d e1b0ce82 3a000001 f421070d  .*.........:..!.
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): code around lr:
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1e8ca8 e59d3008 e250a000 0a000006 e0218693  .0....P.......!.
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1e8cb8 e1a02007 e3a08000 e58d8034 ebff9b50  . ......4...P...
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1e8cc8 e58d8020 eaffff17 e3e00000 e28ddf8d   ...............
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1e8cd8 e8bd8ff0 ebff9b56 e594c018 e59c3000  ....V........0..
08-11 13:00:38.166: INFO/DEBUG(2188): 5c1e8ce8 e1a01000 eafffee6 e59d4024 eafffea8  ........$@......
```

---

```
8-11 13:00:38.507: INFO/ActivityManager(2685): Process com.** (pid 19011) has died.
08-11 13:00:38.507: INFO/WindowState(2685): WIN DEATH: Window{427d2b00 com.**/com.**.FragmentActivity paused=false}
08-11 13:00:38.507: WARN/ActivityManager(2685): Force removing ActivityRecord{426dfe90 com.**/.FragmentActivity}: app died, no saved state
08-11 13:00:38.517: WARN/WindowManager(2685): Force-removing child win Window{428d1380 PopupWindow:424cf990 paused=false} from container Window{427d2b00 com.**/com.**.FragmentActivity paused=false}
08-11 13:00:38.527: WARN/WindowManager(2685): Failed looking up window
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@42dc49a0 does not exist
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7714)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7705)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:854)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:449)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-11 13:00:38.527: INFO/WindowState(2685): WIN DEATH: null
```

Comment: There's no sigsegv in what you posted, post more data.  All we can tell from that is someone tried to access an invalid pointer.  Due to the low address Most likely a .so file called via JNI didn't do a null check before accessing an array or object pointer.

Comment: @GabeSechan I posted the entire stack.

Comment: Looks like its happening in a deep call to memcpy, from somewhere within an OpenGL call.  Hard to tell more.  If you're calling OpenGL from C++, look for null pointers.  If you're doing it from Java, make sure you aren't passing it things like recycled bitmaps or null pointers.

Comment: If it will happen consistently, try to figure out by logging progress where in your program flow it is occurring (or consider running gdb).  While it's probably your mistake, OpenGL implementation bugs are not unknown on Android devices, but to report one you'd need to reduce it to a minimal set of code which triggers it.

Comment: I am neither using openGl nor NDK. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe Sechan, your comment allowed me to solve the problem. Im my case it was the webView crashing on Android 4.1.2 and I could remember that there was an Android bug with hardware acceleration (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38770 ) I set it in the manifest to false for the whole app and with it the WebView does not crash anymore.